# Reduce URI path in REStful with Java (JAX-RS)

Tags: java, apache, rest, jax-rs, web.xml

I am newbie to java and JAX-RS.i have developed working example for simple application.

now i want to **reduce my url** in RESTFul.

Currently i have **`http://localhost:8084/eshipper_api/apis/api/get_quote`** this url.

its working and giving output.

i want to reduce it and want to **make it like** **`http://localhost:8084/eshipper_api/apis/get_quote`**

My **web.xml**

```
     <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
         <servlet>
           <servlet-name>Eshipper API Application</servlet-name>
           <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
              <init-param>
                 <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
                 <param-value>com.eshipper.client.request</param-value>
              </init-param>
           </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Eshipper API Application</servlet-name>
           <url-pattern>/apis/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>  
     </web-app>
```

Code in **/java/com/eshipper/client/request/RequestHandler.java** which is param value for `com.eshipper.client.request`

```
        @Path("api")
        public class RequestHandler 
        {
           @GET
           @Path("/get_quote")
           public String GetQuote()
           {
               return "GOdddd Working";
           }
        }
```

Please help me for this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `@Path("api")` to `@Path("")`

```
    @Path("")
    public class RequestHandler 
    {
       @GET
       @Path("/get_quote")
       public String GetQuote()
       {
           return "GOdddd Working";
       }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could change your web.xml to:

`<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and set your `@Path("/apis")` and it would do the same thing.

You have your `http://servername/`**context**`/`**web.xml servlet path**`/`**class annotated path**`/`**method annotated path**